# Counting in Hadoop Hive And Show the result more than a given num

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I want to count values similar in a map where key would be the value in the Hive table column and the corresponding value is the count. And count is more than a given num `x`.

For example, 
query:

```
SELECT Col1, COUNT(*) FROM Table GROUP BY Col1
```

result:

```
Key1=2
Key2=1
```

and the given num `x=2`.
So the hive query should return something like :

```
Key1=2.
```

explain:

```
Key1=2 >=2 (ok)
Key2=1 <2  (not ok)
```

Answer (score 1):

Map will be displayed like `{"Key1":2}` If you want  `Key1=2` then use `concat(Col1, '=', cnt)` instead of `map()`:

```
select map(Col1, cnt) as mymap
from(
SELECT Col1, COUNT(*) cnt 
  FROM Table 
 GROUP BY Col1 
HAVING count(*)>=2 --Magic number filter here
)s;
```